# php mysql query from a loop - determine which table rows are Not in the loop

Tags: php, mysql

probably a confusing title - I did find one result in the S.O. archives that I thought would do the trick but still not getting it.

I'm using a function to display all files (to me as an admin) in a directory on the server (this works fine)
I also have filenames stored in a database table...

what I want to do is; while im generating the server file list, also query the table for a matching filename - I'm trying to identify orphans on the server that are not in my db table.

It's seems like I've done this before or it's "easy" task with a query but I'm drawing a total blank and hitting a wall. (if there's not a result for a row, your basic query just looks for the next match and I want to flag the non-matches).

the one solution I found in the S.O. archives is using "NOT IN" the query something like:

```
$files_on_server = "file1,file3,file4,file7";
// Your SQL WHERE clause...
...WHERE `filename` NOT IN ($files_in_server)
```

but that's not doing it for me.
thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: From what you have said `NOT IN` is probably easiest approach.  What is not working?

Comment: Just a follow up - I got the query to work after all however it is the reverse result of what I wanted - `NOT IN` shows me titles in the DB that are not in my server file-list that I create. I was looking for the opposite... something like (psuedo) "look for file1 in the DB table... no match but flag that there was no match for "file1" in the db table... look for file2... and so on

Comment: resolved - I just had to move the echo result outside of the query loop } echo $filename there, and it displayed a blank result also reset $filename == ""  and continued back through the outer-loop of my server-filenames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's all about punctuation. How about single-quoting the values?

```
$files_on_server = "'file1','file3','file4','file7'";
```

But it's usually more preferable to use prepared statements - google for mysqli and PDO.

Comment: it appears that `NOT IN` is the approach then, so I'll keep at it - I'm not getting any result from my query I'm using `mysql_fetch_array(): ` so I must have a typo or problem that I'm missing...

Comment: Like some other answers suggest, it may be $files_on_server vs. $files_in_server. Anyway, quotes are needed for 'File Names Like This.txt'

Comment: I will mark this as answered for confirming `NOT IN` and trouble-shoot my code further.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this `$files_on_server` should match this: `$files_in_server`

```
 $files_on_server = "'file1','file3','file4','file7'";
// Your SQL WHERE clause...
...WHERE `filename` NOT IN ($files_on_server)
```

From reading your question. If you are collecting the file names, you could use a recursive function to put them in an array. then you could implode the array in the **NOT IN** statement

```
NOT IN('" . implode("' , '", $files_on_server) . "')
```

Comment: edited the code to incorperate @full.stack.ex answer also. His is correct.

Comment: ok I Missed your comment earlier before i checked that off. I'll try that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your string:

```
$files_on_server = "file1,file3,file4,file7";
```

Make it into this:

```
$files_on_server = "'file1','file3','file4','file7'";

SELECT *
FROM files
WHERE filename NOT IN ($files_on_server);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with this line:

`$files_on_server = "file1,file3,file4,file7";`

It should be (notice individual quotes):

`$files_on_server = "'file1','file3','file4','file7'";`

But also consider why there are orphaned files. If it is because files got deleted via FTP, consider writing a php interface to delete them instead. When there's large numbers of files to keep track of, the current solution may start slowing down.

Comment: I just gotta throw this one out there... http://php.net/manual/en/book.fam.php :) perpetual beta?

Comment: That looks interesting. If I ever have need for this myself I'll be sure to remember it